# Prompting User Input and Displaying User Output Using An Array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I need help. I need to prompt the user to enter an index between 0 and 9. If the user enters something outside of the array, then I need to use an "if" statement or "try catch" to tell the user "No such score exists". This is what I have so far.

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] GameScores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index between 0 and 9");
    int gamescores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < GameScores.Length;i++)
    {
       GameScores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

  } // end Main
```

Comment: 'If the user enters something outside of the array, then I need to use an "if" statement or "try catch" to tell the user "No such score exists".' Have you tried either of these? (The `if` is the way to go.) What's stopping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using For loop you directly use the contains to  check wheather the desired value is present in array or not.
Try this out.

```
        int[] GameScores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index between 0 and 9");
        int gamescores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (GameScores.Contains(gamescores))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("score exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No such score exists");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
       int[] GameScores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index between 0 and 9");
        int gamescores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (gamescores >= 0 && gamescores<=9)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < GameScores.Length; i++)
            {
                GameScores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number not valid");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks all. I overthink this stuff so much.

Comment: Okay will do. I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

A flexible solution would be:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int scoreSize = 10;
     int[] gameScores = Enumerable.Range(1, scoreSize).ToArray();
     Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index between 0 and {0}", gameScores.Length - 1);
     int selectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if(selectedIndex >= 0 && selectedIndex < gameScores.Length)
          for(int i = 0; i < gameScores.Length; i++)
               gameScores[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     else
         Console.WriteLine("No such score exists");
}
```

This way, if you change your `scoreSize` to `20` for example.

```
int scoreSize = 20;
```

The program will still work as expected and no further change would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple -

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] GameScores = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an index between 0 and 9");
        int gamescores = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (gamescores < 0 || gamescores > 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No such score exists");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GameScores.Length; i++)
            {
                GameScores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }`
```